# Get ID in HOOK_preprocess_container

Tags: 8, forms

I'm currently working a styling of a drupal 8 website. And I'm trying two things.

In HOOK_preprocess_container I want to output a block, I got the block script figured out but I want to filter and output only when the Container ID matches a certain ID. Can someone help me out with this?

Thanks in advance.

My current HOOK:

```
function HOOK_preprocess_container(&$variables) {
  //something like this
  $containerID = //get container ID;

  $block = \Drupal\block\Entity\Block::load('block_id');
  $block_content = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
    ->getViewBuilder('block')
    ->view($block);

  if($containerID == "containerID"){
    $variables['containerblock'] = $block_content;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get that with:

```
$container_id = $variables['element']['#id'];
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you. For next time, how do I find out where to find an ID, name or something else. When I use Kint I don't see this information.